# How to install official released iOS 5 on iPhone 4 installed with iOS 5 beta?

Tags: iphone, ios5

I'm an iPhone developer. I have my iPhone installed with iOS 5 beta. Since now the official release of iOS 5 is out, how can I install that version instead?

iTunes detects that my version is the latest already.

Comment: Doesn't belong here, it goes to superuser.com . I suggest to read FAQ to know.

Comment: agreed ... not a programming question

Comment: If you installed the latest (GM) beta, you've got that version already.

Comment: @Nettogrof and bryanmac Agreed with you guys. That not belong to programming.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways:

Back up your phone, factory reset it, update with iTunes then restore from back-up.

OR

download the GM seed and Option-click RESTORE in iTunes to select the GM seed file.